# Python is there a way to break a loop outside of it (No Error)?

Tags: python, loops, break

This is my code:

```
    while i == 1:
        mess = await message.channel.send("{:.2f}x".format(i))
        i_adding = random.randint(1, 9) /100
        i += i_adding
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

    while i < printing:
        i_adding = random.randint(1, 9) /100
        i += i_adding
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await mess.edit(content="{:.2f}x".format(i))

@client.command()
async def break(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send('Ok, now nothing should be send')
    #break the "while i < printing"
```

i want the last line to break the second loop "while i < printing"
And i dont know how to do it!

Comment: You could add an extra variable like while i < printing and not is_done: and then set is_done = True in break()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do that you will have to do so explicitly e.g. share an Event object, and exit the loop if the even is set.

One possible complication is that [`threading.Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects) is not async-aware and [`asyncio.Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Event) is not thread-safe, so you can either have a multithreaded system, or be able to "break" while waiting for the result of `mess.edit`. I don't know that either matters but there you go.

The simplest and safest would be to simply check if the `event` is set in the loop:

```py
break_event = threading.Event()

...
    while i == 1:
        mess = await message.channel.send("{:.2f}x".format(i))
        i_adding = random.randint(1, 9) /100
        i += i_adding
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

    while i < printing and not break_event.is_set():
        i_adding = random.randint(1, 9) /100
        i += i_adding
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await mess.edit(content="{:.2f}x".format(i))
    break_event.clear()

@client.command()
async def break(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send('Ok, now nothing should be send')
    break_event.set()
```

Comment: Thanks, i had to add some things after it in other parts, but its working now!